# CSS is not loading

Tags: html, css

I've written a piece of CSS, while it does not affect the way my page(s) are displayed.
I use in my HTML  tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

And my style.css file looks like this:

```
@import('CSS/modal.css');
@import('CSS/menu.css');
@import('CSS/content.css');
@import('CSS/footer.css');
@import('CSS/title.css');
```

Yet when I use this:

```
#title {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

To test if it really doesn't load the CSS.

On this part of HTML:

```
 <body>
    <div id="title">
      AMP
    </div>
 </body>
```

It still doesn't display the text in 5em.

EDIT:
It seems that when I put the CSS3 code directly into style.css and do not let it run over the @import() function, it does load correctly, but why is it not working anymore? It worked  fine yesterday, it has always worked perfectly.

Comment: Are the imported CSS files in a directory called `CSS` relative to the `style.css` file?

Comment: Are those CSS files really in a CSS directory? Is the directory titled all uppercase like your links are? Try all lowercase "css". Your server may be set up as case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two mistakes.

This:

```css
#title.css {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

should be:

```css
#title {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

And this:

```css
@import('CSS/modal.css');
@import('CSS/menu.css');
@import('CSS/content.css');
@import('CSS/footer.css');
@import('CSS/title.css');
```

should be:

```css
@import 'CSS/modal.css';
@import 'CSS/menu.css';
@import 'CSS/content.css';
@import 'CSS/footer.css';
@import 'CSS/title.css';
```

`@import url('CSS/title.css');` and `@import 'CSS/title.css';` are both valid forms. What you have is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `.css` from your selector:

```css
#title {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

`#text.css` selector means "select an element that has both `title` id and `css` class".

Comment: Ah, that was stupid of me to put in. But even after removing it it is not changing. I've pressed F5, closed the browser, everything.

This is also not the real CSS3 code I'm speaking of, I've written a much larger piece. But since that didn't apply I tried to use the little title.css to see if it was something in the other script (modal.css) or something else.

Comment: @JesseDijkstra: Are your folder paths correct? You have `href="style.css"` and `@import('CSS/title.css');`.

Comment: @thirtydot: Yes, this is valid, and has always been. Since you're refering to a folder that is called CSS and within that folder you search for the (in this example) 'title.css' file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#title {
 font-size: 5em;
}
```

The Jsfiddle here works: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/g25CD/)

Comment: Somehow it now perfectly enlarges the text to 5em. But why is the
'@import('');' not working any more? It worked before.